# Is there any way of sending mobile notification from java web applications freely

Tags: java, web-applications, sms-gateway

I am developing a web application in Java, in which I want to send notifications or updates to some mobile numbers, in the form of SMS messages.

I have investigated `aspsms` and `now.sms` but both require some amount of charge. In `now.sms` I configured it using GSM phone and balance gets deducted from phone. Is there any other way of sending SMS messages freely from web applications? If any body knows how to configure `now.sms` for HTTP SMSC please do let me know.

Comment: Great!  Yet *another* source of SMSpam.  Unless you're prepared to pay, you shouldn't be sending SMS'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are a lot of services which can send sms for free, way2sms is one of them..
[here](http://codeglobe.blogspot.in/2009/07/way2sms-api.html) and [here](http://codeglobe.in/api/way2sms/17-way2sms-api.html) are some links.

Comment: but how i can i integate it with my web app

Comment: i've updated my answer, added some links to sample code

Comment: i have  just copied and run  that code but it is giving some errors. Please help me i am just engg student.

Comment: you need to be more precise as to the issue, please post the exception trace or info as to what is happening..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://wwwa.way2sms.com/FirstServletsms?custid=
Successful, protection removed
Successful, protection removed
Successful, protection removed
Successful, protection removed
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)

Comment: ok, the request is of the incorrect format then... please look to adjust the params you are sending to the server or look at another library.. (if you pay for a service there is a very good chance that the api will work correctly you can setup an account with way2sms and use the service .

Comment: hey anantha Sharma can i please get your maild . I will mail you my code. Please help me. I am trying from many days. Please

Comment: hey i mailed my complete code

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really free AFAIK the ones that claim to be free push adds to your sms messages to cover the costs.

If you need two way communication, the end user will need to subscribe to your service.
You can check [this service](http://www.openmarket.com/messaging/sms-messaging/free-to-end-user-fteu/).

If you need one way communication you can [email to sms gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) but this solution requires knowing the carrier the end user is on.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may also use fcall.in to send 460 chars sms for free